# Changing x-axis tick labels in reverse plot

Tags: ggplot2

I try to have an axis going from 0 to 24 (that represent hours in a day). With tick labels at 6, 12 and 18 too.

I am struggling, I tried already scale_x_discrete and scale_x_continuous and ylim, but the axis always goes from 0 to 25... :(

Thanks in avance for your help

[image]

```
Categ <- c("Employment","Voluntary work","Householdchores","Household member care","Personal care","Study","Sports and outdoor",
             "Leisure","Travel or unspecified","Sleep")
  Regime <- c("Unemp.", "Part-time 1" ,"Part-time 2" ,"Full time"  , "Overtime")
  Share <- c(0.00,0.10,3.71,1.14,2.70,0.18,0.37,5.55,1.28,8.96,1.29,0.10,4.13,1.13,3.10,0.11,0.18,3.73,1.72,8.50,3.79,0.13,2.89,0.78,2.43,0.04,0.22,3.94,1.69,8.09,5.78,0.08,1.96,
    0.76,2.17,0.03,0.24,3.44,1.48,8.05,7.88,0.10,1.46,0.57,1.91,0.02,0.20,2.73,1.33,7.80)
  data <- data.frame(Regime = rep(rev(Regime), each=10),
                     Category = rep(Categ,times=5),
                     Share = Share)
  pct2 <- ggplot(data, 
         aes(x = Regime, y = Share)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = Category),
             stat = "identity", colour="black")+
    coord_flip() +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + 
    scale_fill_manual("Legend", values = c("Employment" = "#F4A582", "Voluntary work" = "#FDDBC7", "Household chores" = "#92C5DE", "Household member care" = "#4393C3", "Personal care" = "#737373", "Study" = "#969696", "Sports and outdoor" = "#BDBDBD", "Leisure" = "#D9D9D9", "Travel or unspecified"= "#F0F0F0", "Sleep" = "#F6E8C3")) +
    ylim(0,24)
  print(pct2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do (I'm adding `scale_y_continuous(...)` and I'm omitting `ylim(0,24)`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Regime, y = Share)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill = Category), stat = "identity", colour="black") +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = as.numeric(seq(1:24))) +
    theme(panel.background = element_blank()) + 
    scale_fill_manual("Legend", values = c("Employment" = "#F4A582", "Voluntary work" = "#FDDBC7", "Household chores" = "#92C5DE", "Household member care" = "#4393C3", "Personal care" = "#737373", "Study" = "#969696", "Sports and outdoor" = "#BDBDBD", "Leisure" = "#D9D9D9", "Travel or unspecified"= "#F0F0F0", "Sleep" = "#F6E8C3"))
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, it works perfectly!